# Using multiple PushSharp PushBroker instances

Tags: c#, multithreading, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

Currently my team is at the design phase of a push notifications application targeting APNS and GCM that will be using PushSharp (v 2.2.1) as the core component that handles the sending of the notifications.

We are expecting to have about 200K subscribers (device tokens). The application needs to send two types of messages; one that will be send to all subscribers and another one that will be send to smaller amounts of 5K to 15K subscribers. More than one type of message may be scheduled for sending at the same time.

We are thinking about using multiple threads or tasks to send each individual message. We are leaning towards having a fixed number of tasks dedicated to each type of message, e.g. two tasks for the first type and four tasks for the second type. Each task will be responsible for the whole process of sending the message, so each task will have a separate (private) instance of the PushSharp.PushBroker class to handle the job. After the job is completed, if there is a new message of the supported type scheduled to be send, then the task will handle it otherwise the task will be disposed. On the other hand, if a message will be scheduled for sending and all tasks are busy, it will have to wait until the first task of the appropriate type will become available. In conclusion, more than one instances of the PushSharp.PushBroker will be running in different tasks/threads in the same application (e.g. a windows service).

- Would this be a safe approach in terms of performance, required resources or bandwidth?
- Regarding thread safety and taking into account that PushSharp internally uses multithreading are there any synchronization issues that we need to be aware of?
- Finally, will there be any issue if connections to APNS or GCM will be opened and utilized by multiple instances of the Pushsharp.PushBroker class concurrently? (Each instance will manage its own connections).

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

George